# Function to process all angles of a full circle in a zigzag order

Tags: python, numpy

I need to calculate values for a lot of angles in degrees. In order to build up the coarse shape fast, and the fine bits in between later, I want to calculate the shape in this order (0°, 180°, 90°, 270°,45°,135°...)

The following code does what I want. I wonder: Is there a way to do that in a more straightforward way? It needs to work for any (whole) number (eg. 72, or 7465)

Thanks for your help.

```
import numpy as np

def evenly_spaced_star_order(number):
    
    Total=np.linspace(0,360,number,endpoint=False)

    Res=[]
    
    for devider in [2**_ for _ in range(1000)]:
        for counter in range(devider):
            Number=(counter*len(Total))//devider
            if np.isfinite(Total[Number]):
                Res.append(Total[Number])
                Total[Number]=np.nan
        if np.all(np.isnan(Total)):
            break
    return(Res)
print(evenly_spaced_star_order(16))
```

Comment: I think you could think in terms of regular polygons. First go for the corners of a square (0,180,90,270), then the remaining corners of a hexagon, then the remaining corners of an octagon. I don't know if this i easy enough to consider.

Comment: It would be easy enough, but for example for 10 it would not yield the 0,180,72,252... I need, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution recursively separates the even- and odd-numbered indexes.  The odd-numbered rows are then put at the end of the final list (in order), and the even-numbered rows are recursively split apart again.

My order is consistent with your original function, but it is a lot faster (by an order of magnitude or more) and it does indeed work for any whole number.

```
# recursive evenly_spaced_star_order()
def esso(number):
    def interleave(arr):
        return arr if len(arr) <= 1 else np.append(interleave(arr[0::2]), arr[1::2])
    
    return interleave(np.linspace(0,360,number,endpoint=False))

print(esso(16))
```

My timings:

```
%timeit evenly_spaced_star_order(16)
885 µs ± 8.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit esso(16)
60.1 µs ± 998 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit evenly_spaced_star_order(1000)
5.88 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit esso(1000)
111 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Mine will perform better and better as the number of points increases (as compared to the original code).

**Second solution**

It's not nearly as pretty, but the order is closer and it is still faster.

```
def esso2(number):
    def interleave(arr):
        if arr.shape[0] <= 1:
            return arr
        mid = arr.shape[0] // 2
        it1 = iter(interleave(arr[0:mid]))
        it2 = iter(interleave(arr[mid:]))
        return sum(zip(it1, it2), ()) + tuple(it2)
    return np.array(interleave(np.linspace(0,360,number,endpoint=False)))
print(esso2(72))
```

Comment: Nice one, that is way more elegant and straightforward, one might consider using a loop instead of the recursion, but that is only a style issue

Comment: Further testing results in different results to the original function, some of which are not so nice (I tryed 72, which gives 0, 320, which are too close to each other....)

Comment: Edited with a second solution.  Still not an exact match, but not that far off, either.  Perhaps a difference of a left/right swap.